# for loop within for loop getting invalid syntax

Tags: python, for-loop

Hi I am quite new to python and struggling with creating a for loop within a for loop. I want the bottom 3 lines to loop. Many thanks!

```
for restaurant in sorted_list:
    wks_res.append_row([
        restaurant["name"],
        restaurant["rating"],
        restaurant["user_ratings_total"],
        restaurant['reviews'][0]['text'],
        restaurant['reviews'][1]['text'],
        restaurant['reviews'][2]['text'],
])
```

The way I tried it is as follows:

```
for restaurant in sorted_list:
   wks_res.append_row([
       restaurant["name"],
       restaurant["rating"],
       restaurant["user_ratings_total"],
       for reviews in restaurant['reviews']:
          reviews['text'],

])
```

Comment: Does `append_row` specifically need a *list*, or can it be an arbitrary iterable?

Answer (score 3):

This should work. Watch out for those brackets, they are rearranged on purpose. Check out list comprehension on Internet for more info about this.

```
for restaurant in sorted_list:
   wks_res.append_row([
       restaurant["name"],
       restaurant["rating"],
       restaurant["user_ratings_total"]] +
       [rev["text"] for rev in restaurant["reviews"]]

)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't use a for loop inside an expression.

This should works :

```
for restaurant in sorted_list:
   # create the list to append
   row = [
       restaurant["name"],
       restaurant["rating"],
       restaurant["user_ratings_total"]
   ]
   # expend this list with 'reviews'
   for review in restaurant['reviews']:
          row.append(review['text'])
   # append the list to wks_res
   wks_res.append_row(row)
```

alternatively you can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
row = [
   restaurant["name"],
   restaurant["rating"],
   restaurant["user_ratings_total"]
] + [review['text'] for review in restaurant['reviews']]
```

Comment: I think what you mean is that "you can't use a for loop inside an expression".  Also, note that in Python 3, you can do this: `row = [restaurant['name'], restaurant['rating'], restaurant['user_ratings_total'], *[review['text'] for review in restaurant['reviews']]`.  I'm not sure it's great from a readability point of view, but it's possible. :-)

Comment: I'd use `operator.itemgetter` here. Define `get_stuff = itemgetter("name", "rating", "user_ratings_total"` before the loop, then `row = list(get_stuff(restaurant))` inside the loop. The nested loop can be replaced with `row.extend(r['text'] for r in restaurant['reviews'])`.

Comment: If you *really* want to go crazy, `row = list(chain(get_stuff(restaurant), (r['text'] for r in restaurant['reviews'])))`. (`chain` comes from the `itertools` module.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! This indeed worked:

```
for restaurant in sorted_list:
   wks_res.append_row([
      restaurant["name"],
      restaurant["rating"],
      restaurant["user_ratings_total"]] +
      [rev["text"] for rev in restaurant["reviews"]]
```

)